# Why is there no audio support while we use native screen reocrding of ubuntu(Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS)

Tags: 22.04, screen, audio-recording, video-recording

So i have recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, its a really good stepup from the previous versions. My only issue is ,in the native screen recording only the screen(display) gets recorded and audio dose not get recorded.

Then later i tried installing Kazam and other screen recording apps, in that audio gets recorded but screen(display) dose not get recorded.

is there a solution for the screen recording with audio?

Answer (score 0):

You could install `OBS Studio` as per below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio
sudo apt update
sudo apt install obs-studio
```

To record audio:

- Open OBS and click the + icon in the Sources box at the bottom of the screen.
- Choose Audio Input Capture from the menu that appears.
  A pop-up menu will appear. Name your source or leave it and then click OK.
- Click the drop-down menu next to Device and select your desired microphone from the menu.

Within the Audio Mixer box, you’ll see a new channel appear. You can monitor these meters to set your recording levels.

More information is [found here](https://www.movavi.com/support/how-to/how-to-record-screen-with-obs.html).